# QMutex in slots

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mutex

Suppose to have the following QT code (QT 5.3.1):

```
void SenderClass::runSignal()
{
    emit mySignal();
}

void ReceiverClass::ReceiverClass()
{
    ...
    connect (senderClassRef, SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(mySlot()) );
}

void ReceiverClass::mySlot()
{
    //Long operation executions
    Sleep(1000);
    qDebug() << "1";
    Sleep(1000);
    qDebug() << "2";
    Sleep(1000);
    qDebug() << "3";
}
```

Calling runSignal() consecutively it happens that console displays something like:

> 1 2 1 3 2 3

The 2 classes live in the same thread.
Do I have to use a QMutexLocker in slots?? Or is there an another way to have an ordered output like:

> 1 2 3 1 2 3

so preventing a call of *mySlot()* function if there's still one executing.

**UPDATE**

Here follow a real code snippet.
The sender:

```
//Sender.h

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextBrowser>

class Receiver;

class Sender : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Sender(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QTextBrowser *textBrowser;
    Receiver* receiver;

signals:
    void buttonClickedSignal();

public slots:
    void ButtonClickedSlot();
};

//Sender.cpp

#include "Sender.h"
#include "Receiver.h"

#include <QObject>

Sender::Sender(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
    pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));
    pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(150, 30, 75, 23));
    pushButton->setText("Button");
    textBrowser = new QTextBrowser(this);
    textBrowser->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textBrowser"));
    textBrowser->setGeometry(QRect(50, 90, 256, 192));

    receiver = new Receiver(this);

    QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ButtonClickedSlot()));
}

void Sender::ButtonClickedSlot()
{
    emit buttonClickedSignal();
}
```

The receiver:

```
//Receiver.h
#include "Sender.h"

class Receiver : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Receiver(Sender *sender);

    Sender *m_sender;

public slots:
    void ReceiverSlot();
};

//Receiver.cpp
#include "Receiver.h"

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QApplication>

Receiver::Receiver(Sender *sender)
{
    m_sender = sender;

    QObject::connect(m_sender, SIGNAL(buttonClickedSignal()), this, SLOT(ReceiverSlot()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void Receiver::ReceiverSlot()
{
    m_sender->textBrowser->append("1");
    QThread::msleep(100);
    qApp->processEvents();
    m_sender->textBrowser->append("2");
    QThread::msleep(100);
    qApp->processEvents();
    m_sender->textBrowser->append("3");
    QThread::msleep(100);
    qApp->processEvents();
    m_sender->textBrowser->append("4");
    QThread::msleep(100);
    qApp->processEvents();
}
```

Clicking the button quickly results in not consecutive numbers in QTextBrowser, even if a QueuedConnection is set.

[image: Output]

**UPDATE 2**

What I would like to achieve is a queued access to the ReceiverSlot. The user can click the button with any freedom (when he wants and at any speed). The ReceiverSlot cannot miss any event. I need some sort of event queuing so that (long) operations in the ReceiverSlot are always executed, maybe delayed, but executed.

Comment: i'm noive in qt. can you try making signal a blocking call and see? may be they are being async.

Comment: Put a flag before executing and reset it after execution is done. Skip new execution if old one is in progress.

Comment: Does it reproduce in a fresh project (just connect a button and put the qDebug(); Sleep() in the slot). If not, it's something in your code that you haven't posted.

Comment: I just tested it, it doesn't reproduce. Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces it.

Comment: QT is not single-threaded. This is expected behaviour, yes?

Comment: the observer behavior cannot be possible with the information you provided. There must be something else.

Comment: This `long operation of executions`. Is there something like `QApplication::processEvents` somewhere in there? Or perhaps you create a local event loop somewhere?

Comment: @PureW Events processing is done in the main thread, so in this scenario Qt is single-threaded - so no, this is not expected behaviour.

Comment: @sashoalm I've update the post with a real working and compilable example.

Comment: @thuga: yes I'm using `QApplication::processEvents` to do not freeze the application. But even if I use `Qt::QueuedConnection` the slot is invoked in a parallel way. Could `QMutexLocker` be the only solution available? Why is `Qt::QueuedConnection` not working?

Comment: If you're clicking quickly, the call to `qApp->processEvents()` can cause the signal to get emitted again, which mean that your slot gets called recursively.  It has nothing to do with threading.

Comment: @DanMilburn: what about `Qt::QueuedConnection`: should not block slot call until slot code has been executed?

Comment: No.  QueuedConnection doesn't block anything, it causes the slot to be called asynchronously via an event.  But you are telling Qt to deliver the events!  So it will still get called unless you do something to prevent it.

Comment: One more question: if I'd remove the `qApp->processEvents()`, could it prevent the slot to be called while the same it's still executing? Just to better understand, I know this would freeze the app.

Comment: @ABCplus Nested event loop, duh. Of course it will happen that way, what did you expect.

Comment: @ABCplus Yes, removing `QApplication::processEvent` calls would stop the slot being called while it is still being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `QApplication::processEvents` and move the long operation that freezes your GUI to a new thread. You can use for example a worker object that you move to a new thread. There is a [good example of this in the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details).

You should also read [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects) to learn more about threads and events in Qt. There is an exact same situation as yours explained in the [forcing event dispatching](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#7494f2b4836907fc1c09311e3a0305e6) part:

*Be very careful when reentering the event loop “by other paths”: it can lead to unwanted recursions! Let’s go back to the Button example. If we call QCoreApplication::processEvents() inside the doWork() slot, and the user clicks again on the button, the doWork() slot will be invoked again:*

- *main(int, char **) QApplication::exec()*
- *[…]*
- *QWidget::event(QEvent *)*
- *Button::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)*
- *Button::clicked()*
- *[…]*
- *Worker::doWork() // first, inner invocation*
- *QCoreApplication::processEvents() // we manually dispatch events and…*
- *[…]*
- *QWidget::event(QEvent * ) // another mouse click is sent to the
  Button…*
- *Button::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)*
- *Button::clicked() // which emits clicked() again…*
- *[…]*
- *Worker::doWork() // DANG! we’ve recursed into our slot.*

In general you want to avoid `QApplication::processEvents` and creating local event loops. If you have these in your code, then you should redesign it so you won't have to use these.

Worker object examlpe from the docs:

```
 class Worker : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     QThread workerThread;

 public slots:
     void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
         // ...
         emit resultReady(result);
     }

 signals:
     void resultReady(const QString &result);
 };

 class Controller : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     QThread workerThread;
 public:
     Controller() {
         Worker *worker = new Worker;
         worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
         connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
         connect(this, SIGNAL(operate(QString)), worker, SLOT(doWork(QString)));
         connect(worker, SIGNAL(resultReady(QString)), this, SLOT(handleResults(QString)));
         workerThread.start();
     }
     ~Controller() {
         workerThread.quit();
         workerThread.wait();
     }
 public slots:
     void handleResults(const QString &);
 signals:
     void operate(const QString &);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn my comments into a proper answer:

If, when in your slot you call `qApp->processEvents()` there is a mouse press event waiting to be delivered to the button, it will be delivered, and the `clicked()` signal will be emitted again, and thus your slot will be called again.

A `QMutex` will not help, because there is no threading involved.  Adding one would most likely result in your program deadlocking.

Using `Qt::QueuedConnection` doesn't help, because this posts an event to the queue which, when processed, will result in your slot being invoked.  So it just, at best, delays it until the next time you call `qApp->processEvents()`.

In the context of your example, my suggestion would be to get rid of the queued connection, and instead disable the button while the slot is working.  This will prevent the `clicked()` signal being emitted again, and also show the user that they shouldn't be trying to click on the button at this time.

If for whatever reason you don't want to do that, you could add a flag to your receiver class to prevent recursive calls.  Something like this will do the trick, although it's not very pretty:

```
void Receiver::ReceiverSlot()
{
  if( m_inSlot )
    return;
  m_inSlot = true;
  // do work
  m_inSlot = false;
}
```

Comment: The "button" cannot be disabled in my application because the user should have the freedom to emit the signal when he wants and at any speed. I quoted "button" because my application is more complex, but it's fine to think that the button cannot be disabled.

Comment: Moreover, I cannot use a boolean to control accesses to the slot otherwise I could miss some events, and I can't.